# JS set cookie not being read in PHP

Tags: php, javascript, cookies

OK, this is driving me bonkers. I've not even been able to get debugging code working here.

Using https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie , I set a cookie:

```
var link=$.getQueryParam('q');
var cookie_name="project_"+q+"_diff";
$.cookie(cookie_name,true,{expires:7,path:'/'});
```

I try to read this cookie in a PHP script:

```
$cookie_name="project_".$q."_diff"; 
if($_COOKIE[$cookie_name]=='true') 
  {
    echo "<!-- Cookie Status is TRUE -->";
    // stuff
  }
else 
  {
    echo "<!-- Cookie Status is FALSE for cookie '$cookie_name' \n All cookies: ".print_r($_COOKIE,true)."\n-->";
    // Other stuff
  }
```

I verify in Chrome's console on various page reloads that the JS cookie is, in fact, set, and I can access it later.

The source code result?

```
<!-- Cookie Status is FALSE for cookie 'project_80afd7a53462bb02dfd39e359ac3f291_diff' 
 All cookies: Array
(
)
-->
```

I also ran the following in the console, based on another StackOverflow question, and retrieved the result later in the console but with still not output to the JS.

```
function createCookie(name,value,days) {
if (days) {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setTime(date.getTime()+(days*24*60*60*1000));
    var expires = "; expires="+date.toGMTString();
}
else var expires = "";
document.cookie = name+"="+value+expires+"; path=/; domain=.compute.amazonaws.com";
}
```

I'm not getting ANY cookies back. The setup is a bit odd (running the PHP on a rendered Jinja template) but all other standard variables are working, and I just need a session long user toggle and cookies seem to be the obvious (if uncooperative) solution. I'm open to suggestions if no one can figure this out ...

Comment: Verify that the browser is sending the cookie to the server. it will be in the request header.

Comment: One possible cause: Your JS code is being served from a different domain than the PHP code, and thus the cookies it creates are for that domain and are not available to your PHP code.

Comment: I just ended up working around it and doing the whole thing in Javascript, which works. I think it was because the headers and variables were being dealt with in Python, which wasn't passing it as a cookie to the PHP engine.

Answer (score 0):

I have this problem too. I resolved it by deleting domain in cookie's description.

Example:

```
document.cookie="username=John Doe; expires=Thu, 18 Dec 2013 12:00:00 UTC; path=/";
```

P.S. I find this problem in IE, Chrome and Opera. In Firefox it works.

Comment: StackOverflow is an english-speaking site. Please refrain from using other languages or translations. There is a russian version if you're interested: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/

Answer (score -1):

put this code in your index.php page

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['uniqueID'])=='')
{
$uniquenum = rand(1000, 10000);
setcookie('uniqueID',$uniquenum,time() + (86400 * 7)); // 86400 = 1 day
}
```

than fetch cookie value using

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['uniqueID']) && !empty($_COOKIE['uniqueID']))
{
}
```

Comment: `isset` returns a boolean value, i'm not sure why u check it against an empty string